# Is it normal for gradients to be extremely large in a deep convnet?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I just finished implementing a convolutional neural network from scratch. This is the first time I've done this. When testing my backpropagation algorithm, the outputted delta values for the weights are extremely large compared to what the original value was. For example, all my weights are initialized to a random number between -0.1 and 0.1, but the delta values outputted are around 75000. This obviously is much too big of a change, and it requires a very small learning rate to even be near functional. A learning rate like 0.01 seems like the convention but mine needs to be at least 0.0000001, leading me to believe I'm doing something wrong. The thing is I don't see how the deltas couldn't be large. To get the derivative of weights with regard to the cost function I convolve the activations of the previous layer (mostly positive due to leaky reLu) with the previous errors (all either 0.1 or 1 due to the derivative of leaky reLu). Obviously the sum of all these positive numbers will get very large as it propagates through the layers. Did I skip a step somewhere? Is this an exploding gradient problem? Should I use gradient clipping or batch normalization?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the convolutions -0.1 to 0.1 seems extremely large. Try something like 0.01 or even less.

If you want to do a more insightful initialization you can take a look at glorot (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf?hc_location=ufi) or he (https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf) initializations.

The crux is to initialize with either uniform or gaussian values with mean 0 and standard deviation equal to square root of the input channels.